# What is Radius of Convergence used for?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, applications

What is the applications for "Radius of convergence"? I haven't been successful in finding any information about the applications, just a lot of information about how to calculate and what it is...

Thanks for all the help

Comment: It's for knowing when a series converges.  Or better yet, when it doesn't.  If you know a series doesn't converge, you know there isn't any point in trying to find a limit.  Similarly, if you know a series converges, you know you can, in principle, find its limit.

Comment: What is it good for? When do you use this information?

I mean do you use it in signal processing or where?

Comment: You use it any time you're considering a series.  So, sure, signal processing.  Or probability.  Or statistics.  It's a basic idea in the foundations of all these fields.